# How do I find the characters length of a utf8 encoded binary in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

How do I find the characters length of a utf8 encoded binary in Erlang?

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Binaries in Erlang are sequences of bytes. Are you asking how to find the number of bytes in a binary, or how to find the number of characters, if binary is interpreted as UTF8 string? Your solution with the conversion to list gives the former.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka Sorry my mistake, I meant to find the number of characters, not the number of bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function [string:length](https://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#length-1), it - among other string representations - accepts a binary with UTF8 encoded string as its argument and returns the number of characters.

Comment: Thank you. I need to pay more attention to docs. :)